# Unit test stub for google authenticator barcode scanning using PHPUnit in Laravel

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, phpunit, google-authenticator

Please help me to find out the solution.

1. Does anyone know how to write a unit test stub using PHPUnit for scanning a barcode?
   FYI :
   In our application, two-factor authentication used(google authenticator). When users enter a valid username and password next screen displayed with barcode, we scan that barcode using the google-authenticator app on mobile then 6 digit code is generated, which we enter in web application then redirects to the home page.
2. How to set a cookie while writing unit test stub for login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For point 2 :
I am able to set cookies (json encoded array) with requests while unit testing in laravel.

```
$cookie = ['cookiename' => \Crypt::encryptString(json_encode(array('cookieValue' => 1)))];

  $this->call('post', 'login', [
        'username' => user1,
        'password' => 'test',
        '_token' => csrf_token(),
        'remember'  => 'on',
    ], $cookie)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an abstraction for your 2FA
2. Make Google Authenticator the default implementation
3. Create a fake implementation that suits your needs. This could be a fixed six digit code that is always valid or you make it configurable
4. Swap the default implementation with the fake in your tests
5. Test the scenarios you need to test in your login process
6. Create a manual test to make sure that your Google Authenticator implementation is actually working

I know this answer is rather abstract, but your question was not very concrete either. If you can provide more details, I'd be happy to go into it.

Comment: In laravel application, two-factor authentication is used for login. Google authenticator is used, we are failing to write unit test case for scanning the barcode and generation of 6 digit code. It will be very helpful if anyone knows how to write unit test for google authenticator using PHPUnit.

Comment: Yes, I got this. That's the reason I suggested you create an abstraction for the 2FA that you can stub or fake, so it becomes testable. Using the actual Google Authenticator in an automated test is not something you want to do. I don't even know if that would be feasible but I wouldn't mess with it anyway. The only thing relevant to your app is that the user provides a valid code. Whether this code comes form Google Authenticator, a hardware token or a sms code doesn't matter. Therefore: go with the abstraction and fake it. That's the solution you can control.

Comment: I didn't get your point on how to implement a unit test stub for google authenticator.

Comment: My point is: You don't have to. If you want to verify that your app is validating against a second factor, then you should do exactly that. It doesn't matter whether it's Google Authenticator or anything else.